# setting async false in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a situation where I call a server side action method (an MVC5 application), and it does not return any results unless I set async false. I am concerned that eventually this option will not be supported by most browesers, and at that point, my code will cease to work. What should I do protect myselg against this eventuality

Comment: If it's not *actually* returning results w/ an async request then there's something on the server side that's disallowing XHR requests. Are you sure the issue is that, or are you trying to use the results before the call actually completes? It's unlikely browser support for async requests would go away, at least any time soon, since there are occasional use-cases. Most of them are bad use cases, but that's a separate discussion.

Comment: @DaveNewton Are you saying that synchronous AJAX doesn't use XHR? Can the server really tell the difference between sync and async calls?

Comment: @Barmar Hm no, in my head it was right.